# Puppeteer newPage() freezes/ never resolves nor rejects Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, puppeteer

I am using an Ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS and Puppeteer 10.0.0. My Problem is that the browser.newPage() function never resolves. So basicly in the console it alsways loggs Start but never 1 nor 2. I have tried a different puppeteer version or puppeteer-core with my own chromium version. I even installed an VM on my Pc and it works there but not on my Server.

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

var adresse = "https://www.google.de/"

async function test() {
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        "headless": true,
        "args": [
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
        ]
    })
    console.log("Start")
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    console.log("1")
    await page.goto(adresse)
    console.log("2")
    console.log(page)
        
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}


}

test()
```

Comment: I just tried your code on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com and my server and it worked fine for me.

But it didn't work on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com with the function i had to remove the `async function test() { }`

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me on my local pc too. I even tried it inside a virtual Machine and rentet another ubuntu server. But the server it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Had to install chromium, fonts and some necessary libs to make it work adding docker file to do the same

```
FROM node:lts AS app
RUN mkdir /codebase
WORKDIR /codebase
# We don't need the standalone Chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/google-chrome
# Install Google Chrome Stable and fonts
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the browser work with Puppeteer.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl gnupg -y && apt-get install libx11-xcb1 \
  && curl --location --silent https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```